# XSLT1.0 copy all nodes and add a few similar nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have xml and I would like to add a few  elements, but without affecting the other  elements that are already there. The order of the elements is not important. But one of the new elements is not being added, how to fix it?

**Input XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <InterchangeHeader>InterchangeHeader</InterchangeHeader>
    <SG0>
        <UNH>UNH</UNH>
        <BGM>BGM</BGM>
        <DTM>DTM</DTM>
        <SG26>
            <LIN>
                <E1082>000010</E1082>
                <C212>
                    <E7143>SRV</E7143>
                </C212>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <E4347>1</E4347>
                <C212>
                    <E7140>000010</E7140>
                    <E7143>IN</E7143>
                </C212>
            </PIA>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>21</E6063>
                    <E6060>2100.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>170</E6063>
                    <E6060>2100.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
        </SG26>
        <SG26>
            <LIN>
                <E1082>000020</E1082>
                <C212>
                    <E7143>SRV</E7143>
                </C212>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <E4347>1</E4347>
                <C212>
                    <E7140>000020</E7140>
                    <E7143>IN</E7143>
                </C212>
            </PIA>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>21</E6063>
                    <E6060>2100.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>170</E6063>
                    <E6060>0.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
        </SG26>
        <SG26>
            <LIN>
                <E1082>000030</E1082>
                <C212>
                    <E7143>SRV</E7143>
                </C212>
            </LIN>
            <PIA>
                <E4347>1</E4347>
                <C212>
                    <E7140>000030</E7140>
                    <E7143>IN</E7143>
                </C212>
            </PIA>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>21</E6063>
                    <E6060>2100.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>170</E6063>
                    <E6060>1900.000</E6060>
                    <E6411>EA</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
        </SG26>
        <UNS>
            <E0081>S</E0081>
        </UNS>
    </SG0>
    <InterchangeTrailer>InterchangeTrailer</InterchangeTrailer>
</root>
```

**MY XSLT** In the first part, I copy everything, and then I try to change

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:ext="urn:ext" exclude-result-prefixes="ext msxml">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SG26[not(QTY/C186/E6063=59)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>59</E6063>
                    <E6060>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'status'"/>
                    </E6060>
                    <E6411>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'status'"/>
                    </E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="SG26[not(QTY/C186/E6063=60)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>60</E6063>
                    <E6060>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'status2'"/>
                    </E6060>
                    <E6411>
                        <xsl:value-of select="'status2'"/>
                    </E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to add a few  elements, but without affecting the other  elements that are already there. The order of the elements is not important. But one of the new elements is deleted, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you talking about a case where an `SG26` meets both conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can solve it as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:ext="urn:ext" exclude-result-prefixes="ext msxml">
    
    <xsl:param name="elements-to-add-rtf">
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>59</E6063>
                    <E6060>status</E6060>
                    <E6411>status</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
            <QTY>
                <C186>
                    <E6063>60</E6063>
                    <E6060>status2</E6060>
                    <E6411>status2</E6411>
                </C186>
            </QTY>
    </xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:variable name="elements-to-add" select="msxml:node-set($elements-to-add-rtf)"/>
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="SG26">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$elements-to-add/QTY[not(C186/E6063 = current()/QTY/C186/E6063)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that the XSLT 1 specific use of the namespace for the extension function `node-set` is processor dependent, as your code declared the prefix and namespace that works with Microsoft processors I assumed you are working with one of them and used that prefix.

Comment: Why not simply use 2 `xsl:if` instructions?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, well, "to add a few elements" will probably then require more than two for the general use case.

Comment: It would still be simpler than this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, you usually don't hesitate to post your suggestions as an answer instead of trying to debate with me about my coding style. Why use XSLT 1, no? Isn't XSLT 3 much simpler than XSLT 2 and that much simpler than XSLT 1?

Comment: I am still waiting for OP to clarify the problem. As for the XSLT version, perhaps you do not realize that most people do not have a choice.

Comment: Ah, yes, those poor XSLT 1 slaves, still waiting to be freed from that misery they were born into. But JSON has come to rescue them and make everyone's life simple and easy.